# How make request more readable and scalable?

Tags: mysql

i have request:

```
SELECT user_id FROM merchant_data 
WHERE user_id IN (
    SELECT user_id FROM merchant_data 
    WHERE merchant_id = 1134 
      AND created_date = '2022-12-02' 
    GROUP BY user_id 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 2) 
  AND merchant_id = 1167 
  AND created_date = '2022-12-02' 
GROUP BY user_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

That request return me data from something like log table. In this case i need to get all users that have 2 more rows with merchant_id == 1134 and 2 rows merchant_id == 1167. But how make it for 4 or 5 or 6 condition like merchant_id == ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id FROM merchant_data 
WHERE created_date = '2022-12-02' 
  AND merchant_id IN (1134, 1167, 1186, ...)
GROUP BY user_id 
HAVING SUM(merchant_id = 1134) >= 2
   AND SUM(merchant_id = 1167) >= 2
   AND SUM(merchant_id = 1186) >= 2
   AND ...
```

That depends on an odd MySQL feature that booleans are literally the integer values 1 for true and 0 for false, so you can SUM() a boolean expression. You can't do that in standard SQL.

You could make it more standard SQL by using CASE expressions with no ELSE clause. CASE returns NULL if there is no match, and COUNT() will ignore NULLs.

```
SELECT user_id FROM merchant_data 
WHERE created_date = '2022-12-02' 
  AND merchant_id IN (1134, 1167, 1186, ...)
GROUP BY user_id 
HAVING COUNT(CASE merchant_id WHEN 1134 THEN 1 END) >= 2
   AND COUNT(CASE merchant_id WHEN 1167 THEN 1 END) >= 2
   AND COUNT(CASE merchant_id WHEN 1186 THEN 1 END) >= 2
   AND ...
```

Comment: But if i need to make it not just for `created_date = '2022-12-02'`. For each condition a different date?

Comment: That wasn't in your question. I've demonstrated a method of counting different subtotals. It's up to you to learn that technique and apply it to other similar questions. I'm not going to play move-the-goalposts.